# Automated warning, if question contains more than X lines of code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions

Again and Again I see questions about non compiling / non working code, where the poster just dumps the contents of his/her entire source file(s) into the questions (sometimes not even mentioning which line the error message refers to).

> **Can we have an automated warning on the "Ask Question Page", if a question contains too much code?**

**Why do I think this is a problem?**

- First of all, it wastes the time of the people that are trying to
  help, because each of them has to go through a lot of (possibly)
  unrelated code.
- Second it makes the question less useful for
  other people, because it is hard to decide, whether or not they face
  the same problem and consequently if the answers apply to them.
- Third (and this might be only true for myself), it often gives me the impression (maybe wrongly), that the questioner isn't willing to put much effort into solving the problem and just looks for someone, who solves the problem for him. Consequently I'm less inclined to even think about the question.

**Why is VTC not enough in my opinion?**

The way its handled currently is to close the question with a link to the [mcve](/help/mcve) page or just ignore it. However, this is not an ideal solution:

1. It requires work by the community (the close queue is already long enough as it is). So better to fend of bad questions, before they reach the system.
2. If someone actually takes the time to figure out, what is wrong with the code, the question might get closed, while he/she is writing the answer and even more time gets wasted.
3. Even if the question is edited and reopened, its often down voted already and has less of a chance to get a good answer.
4. Warning the OP by an automated system beforehand that his question might not be well received and how it can be improved feels far less of an insult, than when your question gets closed by real people.

**How much is too much?**

This is probably the most difficult question to answer. Any criteria we will choose will be a balance between false positives and having enough real hits for the feature to be actually useful.

As a starting point however, the kind of questions I have in mind usually have more than 150 LoCs and are asked by new members of the site (new as in their first or second post). While there may be good questions that fall into the same category, it is my impression that they are REALLY rare and I think the warning can be formulated in such a way that we don't lose them.

So I'd suggest to **warn**, if a question contains **more than 150 LoC** and if the questioner has a **reputation of less than 50**.

One could also add the code/text ratio into the mix, but I feel far less confident about determining a useful bound here.

Coming up with an actual boundary of course requires some statistical data, like "Given a criteria, how many questions would have received a warning, how many of them got closed (true positive) and how many where actually well received (False positive)". I don't know much about how SO works internally, but that sounds not too difficult.

**What should the warning contain?**

As any good warning, it should contain

1. What has triggered the warning?
2. Why am I warned about this?
3. And most importantly: How can I fix it?

Again, just to get the discussion starting, I'd suggest something like this (probably too long):

> Your question contains a lot of code, which indicates that you copy/pasted a lot of your actual code that is not directly related to your problem. This makes it often difficult and time consuming to read and understand the question or to find the bug in your program. It also makes the question less helpful for other users of this site and as a result, decreases the likelihood of people taking the time to help you and might even lead to your question being closed.
>
> If possible, try to create a shorter [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) that demonstrates the same problem explain what parts of the code are relevant and/or make sure that all of this code is actually necessary to reproduce your problem. This might even help you to find a solution to your problem in the process.

**Related questions**

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307636/the-rise-of-unnecessary-code) is basically the same feature request, however I think mine is more specific and I hope I sufficiently addressed the concerns raised in the answer and the comments.

**Disclaimer:** My experience on SO is almost exclusively limited to the c++ tag.

Comment: The tag where this might be an issue is Android where users post their logcat.

Comment: @rene: I see, I didn't think/know of that. I don't know anything about android development in general and logcat in particular but if the format is always the same, it might be possible to discern between code and logfiles. Or it could just be mentioned in the warning, that logs are an exception.

Comment: Well, if it's a warning, it can always be ignored. The question is how often it would be a false positive...

Comment: @Deduplicator: So do you mean, it wouldn't help or (related to rene's comment) it wouldn't be a problem for android?

Comment: I mean I don't have enough data.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes, my hope is that someone who can pull statistics from SO sees this question (and gets interested)

Comment: @rene: That could be solved by implementing method of formatting output, therefore providing a separation between output and code.

Comment: Maybe the restriction should also be removed once a user reaches a certain amount of reputation (maybe 750, which is right after they get access to the low quality posts review queue)

Comment: @Jojodmo 500 is the low quality posts queue - not 750

Comment: @Jojodmo: That is what I suggested, although I'd put the rep bar much lower. The questions that "bother" me are usually asked by newcommers. But anyway, actually finetuning those limits is something that has to be done by someone with access to hard data or a lot more experience than me (which you probably all have).

Comment: I also suggest `Automated warning, if question contains more than X lines of text, and no TL;DR`... Oops this would apply to *your* question.

Comment: Half the terrible code-dump newbie questions don't have the code in a code block.  This feature would work better when combined with automatic heuristics to distinguish computer languages from human languages.  Otherwise this won't trigger when users fail to format their code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: There's a partially-effective feature that tries to help with that. I believe it's also a warning.

Comment: @Basj: The TL;DR is on the top: *"Can we have an automated warning on the "Ask Question Page", if a question contains too much code?"* The question got that long, because I wanted to address the concerns that have been raised in in similar feature request that I linked to (actually, I first wanted to comment on it, then answer and then realized, I should probably make it a separate request, because my goal is a little different). And yes, my questions tend to be somewhat longwinded - sorry for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Actually, I didn't have that impression, but maybe the questions I have in mind were already modified by someone else.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a warning already! Questions that are mostly code cannot be posted. The check requires a ratio of 4 characters of prose per line of code, so a 150 LoC dump would require something like 120 "words" of explanation. This applies to all users with 500 reputation or less.

There's also an "excessively long" warning generated for posts longer than 25000 characters (code or otherwise), and a flag that's raised if they're posted anyway.

It arguably makes bugger all difference; people just write "asdfasdfasdfasdafa dummy text to get rid of warning asdfasdfasdfaf".

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Is this only for new users?

Comment: @MikeMB: Doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get such a warning -or do you actually have to click on submit?

Comment: @MikeMB: Well yes, all validation occurs when you attempt to submit. You don't get a wealth of validation errors _while you type_; that would be silly!

Comment: Note that this wouldn't help them at all to avoid the simple "too many lines of code" warning. That's only avoidable by having fewer lines of code... although [as Peter Cordes notes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311836/automated-warning-if-question-contains-more-than-x-lines-of-code?cb=1#comment280280_311836), this might be circumvented by simply not formatting the code as code at all.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. One line of text and >600 LoC and no warning.

Comment: @MikeMB: Worked for me. I tested it. You can't really predict exactly how the filter will work; the details are kept deliberately hidden.

Comment: "*It arguably makes bugger all difference*" - How do you know how often it has led an asker to reconsider? Without A/B testing you cannot know the difference…

Comment: @Bergi: That's why it's "arguable".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit common sense says that people unconcerned with site quality enough to just spew code at us would also be unconcerned enough to type 10 lines or bargl text to get past any automated blocking feature we implement.

Comment: @Magisch: What? No it doesn't. It's the lowest barrier to getting their problem solved for them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thats exactly what I meant. Maybe my non-native english failed me here, but I wanted to say that such a person **would** definately type 10 lines of garbage to bypass a filter, since they're already determined to ignore the "how to ask" page and post garbage to the site anywaysw.

Comment: @Magisch: Gotcha. Well, that's what I said :)

Comment: @Magisch: Actually, I hope that a lot of those people just don't know the rules / don't know how to write a good question instead of doing this just out of pure layziness (there are certainly enough of those people too). Lets be hones. Folk on the internet is mostly the learning by doing and doesn't read the manuals. So, while I'm pretty sure that not a lot of people really read the "How to ask a good question page", I think that most would react to a warning that says: "You might get a better answer if..." Could be that im just too naive, though.

Comment: @MikeMB: _"Those people just don't know the rules"_ That _is_ laziness, plus a lack of respect to boot. Who joins a community and doesn't bother to read the rules before posting? Pssht. I have _zero_ sympathy for such people, as they have no-one to blame but themselves. All the information's there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Its not about sympathy for anyone, it is about reducing the number of bad questions we have to close, comment on, ignore...

Answer (score 5):

Questions polluted with too much (and irrelevant) code will always be asked. Truth is, if the OP actually wants their question answered, they'll have to eventually learn how to ask. And as @LightnessRacesinOrbit points out, no matter how many warnings or red text you add to a post field, most people just ignore it.

Just flag the question or comment with a link to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and move on.

Comment: You cannot prevent it my hope would be, that they can be reduced by a significant amount, but admittetly that might be unrealistic.I think the important part is to tell them that they could increase their chances to get an answer that way. Not just saying: We don't like that kind of questions.

Comment: @MikeMB yes, I agree that if you word it not like a warning but more of a "hey, you'd probably get a better answer if", that would be much more effective.