# "mostly code" filtering, reputation hiccup

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits, reputation

It seems that the "mostly code" filtering is reputation based [[src](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311836)].
As in, low-reputation users are on a stricter post diet than higher-reputation users.
Makes sense, kinda ... so far.

What makes no sense to me, is that a low-reputation user that, for example, is only trying to do some question re-tagging, and as such is not actively editing the question message, is hindered in doing any non-question-text editing by this "mostly code" filtering. (*Because that "mostly code" filtering kicks in for him (low-rep), while it did not for the OP (high-rep)*).

So, in effect, for these particular cases, low-rep users are asked/required to edit high-rep users' question-text (*ie: back down to comply to low-rep filtering*), before they are allowed to do any other edit stuff ... Which makes no sense at all to me.

I call social/logic/ambiguity BUG on this one.

(*"The road to hell is paved with good intentions"*)

Comment: Please, if you retag question (or edit them in any other way) as a <2k user, you are expected to fix all problems of the question. Make sure that code is correctly formatted, check if the capitalization is correct and so on. Your edits have to be reviewed, which takes time of at least two reviewers. From your last edits, at least two were just retaging and missed other major problems.

Comment: Given that a lot of your edits are on old questions (more than two years ago), it is  very unlikely that mass-retaging of old question is something a user without editing privilege should do.

Comment: The filter applies to all users, regardless of rep. It’s not been around forever, so you can run into it editing older posts. Nothing nefarious or social or unambiguous going in here.

Comment: >"_... you are expected to fix all problems of the question._": I don't subscribe to that rule. If it truly exists, a link/source would be nice. >"_(re-tagging) ... old questions_": Irrelevant, as it happens with new questions too. >"_The filter applies to all users_": My [scr]/source seems to say otherwise. And even if reputation would not play a role, it seems still very easy for OP's to create messages like that. \n (**general**) I understand the reaction to defend that which on holds dear, but so far ... its not making me see your light. Needles to say, the opposite seems also the case.

Comment: @MvGulik: "*I don't subscribe to that rule.*" You can subscribe to whatever you like, but since that's our rule, you have to follow it. Doing tag-only edits that have to be reviewed is a waste of reviewers' time. Going around and adding a bunch of "eric-ide" tags to questions is not valuable enough to the site for people to review or to be worthy of giving you 2 rep.

Comment: Still no link to the page where its stated as such. I doubt it exits. But if it exists, Stack is not for me. (_[current performance-driven-culture victim](https://www.theguardian.com/higher-education-network/2018/feb/16/performance-driven-culture-is-ruining-scientific-research)_)

Comment: Never mind. I know what I needed to know.

Answer (score 11):

> So, in effect, for these particular cases, low-rep users are asked/required to edit high-rep users' question-text (ie: back down to comply to low-rep filtering), before they are allowed to do any other edit stuff ... Which makes no sense at all to me.

That may be because you're not thinking through the full consequences of what you're talking about.

If you do not have the Edit Anywhere privilege (ie: less than 2K rep), then every edit you make *must* be reviewed by a number of other users before it can be applied to the post. That takes up the time of other users. To make better use of the time of others, we expect and require that such edits from lower-rep users fix all, or at least most, of the problems of a post.

That is, tag-only edits from such users are frowned upon. It takes up a limited resource: the time of users who have decided to review edits. The more time is taken up for trivial edits, the less time is available for significant ones.

Since such edits, once approved, give 2 rep to the editor, the edit needs to be significant enough to be worth 2 rep. A tag-only edit is almost certainly not enough.

A code-heavy question is a question that probably needs editing work done on it. So if you're trying to make a tag-only edit to it, you *should* be stopped, since your edit is not fixing enough problems to be worth reviewing or worth giving you 2 rep for.