# "Mostly code" is rejected but "mostly screenshots" goes through

Tags: feature-request, status-review, questions, images, quality-filter

According to its author, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928402/referenceerror-jsondata-is-not-defined was at first rejected for containing mostly code. The author then replaced the code with a screenshot of the code, and this went through.

I find code still preferable to a screenshot of code. If users are to be educated about such things, then shouldn't questions containing "mostly screenshots" also be rejected?

Comment: The problem is that the system doesn't see images as code; the OP had (many) characters of code but *little to no* explanation. As a result, instead of adding a description to *describe* their problem, they removed the code and added images. They didn't address the problem.

Comment: I would be OK if questions with mostly screenshots were rejected, regardless of what these screenshots contain (which the system probably cannot find out).

Comment: [so]'s thoughts seem to be "If we don't allow a new user to use inline images, they won't post images." However, the fact is that it simply results in "If i can't post an inline image, I'll post a hyperlink to one (and not include meaningful information in the question)." The site does attempt to educate users about this, and the Staging Ground will likely be better for it too.

Comment: In the mean time your best thing to do is downvote, Flag/VTC as unclear, and if you like provide a link to [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) in the comments.

Comment: Note that the error that users get, when posting mostly code, *doesn't* tell them to post images either: *"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."* The fact that a user decides that instead of adding details they remove code and post images is just a further reason to downvote. Normally such users haven't actually *read* the message, just saw "too much code" and did *something else (wrong)*. It's common as well that such users have not even taken the tour (which they are prompted to do when signing up) and thus certainly haven't read [ask].

Comment: [Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928402/referenceerror-jsondata-is-not-defined#comment128810079_72928402) "i dont know how to add more message" makes me want to cry.

Comment: It's almost like SO are more interested in getting as many newbies to post questions than making sure they post good questions.

Comment: It's not like that don't know about the edit feature either, @user692942 , as they edited the question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72928402/revisions), and both edits were [before](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72928402/timeline) they made that comment. So they, in fact, *do know* how to "add more message [sic]", they just haven't.

Comment: Usually what seems to happen when authors encounter the too much code error, they either remove the code completely or unformat it.

Comment: Well honestly, why should they bother actually improving this post? When they neither care about SO or their profile, then they can do what they want, there will still be someone who answers their question. Also happened in the linked question, so peoples time got wasted and they still have their answer. It is not only OP's fault for writing the bad question and SO's fault for accepting it, but also our fault for still answering those questions.

Comment: "...this was accepted." Where and how was it accepted? According to the [timeline of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72928402/timeline), it was never reopened??

Comment: @Trilarion: I assume OP means "it was accepted by the system", as in the site software allowed their question to be posted (rather than stopping them before even posting, as the "mostly code" error does).

Comment: Correct, that's what I meant.

Comment: Ok. So accepted may be somewhat misleading. The system simply didn't know that the screenshot was code and the user didn't know or ignored the guideline not to post code in screenshots. However, the manual inspection of other users worked, it was eventually closed and not answered.

Comment: That the system didn't know that the screenshots had code implies that there are legit questions to contain pictures with little to none explanation. Even when we consider questions regarding styling/layout I can't think of a question with pictures, but not much else which would successfully work on SO nowadays. And regarding "and not answered": this is not really true. OP got an answer in a comment, thus learned that there is no need to provide a good question, you still get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 18):

The honest answer is, yes, ideally questions containing very little text and a hyperlink or 2 should ideally be rejected as well; unfortunately they are not.

Although I can't know what truly went through the OP's head, I suspect I can accurately guess what did.

1. The OP wrote their question, as it appears in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72928402/3), but actually put the text of the code, and error, in the body of the question *as text* (hopefully all in a code fence/block)
2. The OP attempted to submit the question, and received the following error:

   > "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

   This is because the ratio of characters within a code fence/block compared to those outside of the block was too high. The number of non-code characters required to code characters is described in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311851).
3. Instead of reading the error in full, the OP likely simply saw "Too much code", and thus to address this, they decided to *remove* the code.
4. To ensure that the code was still in the question, however, they posted it as an image. As they have 1 reputation this could not be inline images.
5. Initially this wasn't presented in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72928402/1) because they removed the hyperlink for some reason (see original [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fe2c574e-6991-4e46-a5b6-da690937e21f/view-source)).
6. As the *new* question ended up being a single sentence, with no code (and no images, though this wouldn't have impacted the acceptability) and passed the minimum character threshold, it was accepted and posted.
7. They then made two further attempts to make the images visible in the question.

Though the OP was informed that images of code isn't acceptable, they then made a claim that they were unable as they *"dont know how to add more message [sic]"*; I read this as they don't know how to use the edit feature, but this seems odd because they had indeed made 2 edits, thus did know how to add more to the content of the question.

---

So, firstly, the system did not actually allow the user to replace the code with images. Although the system likely would have allowed them to post it *had* they included the hyperlinks the original question posted was simply the following:

```
I just learn about API on  100 DAYS of bootcamp web development by
Dr. Angela Yu and i got this eror. Can anyone know how to fix this

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ktHC.png
```

Though there is a hyperlink in there to an image, it's not actually shown in the body of the question.

Next, stopping such things; honestly, I feel that the minimum character requirements are too low nowadays. Questions like "How do I do a Square Root in Python?" were *acceptable* when Stack Overflow first came out, but such questions really aren't any more; they would get heavily downvoted due to a lack of research and likely closed as a duplicate.

I also agree that hyperlinks should not contribute to the minimum number of characters, however, this wouldn't have solved the problem here anyway as (as mentioned before), there was no hyperlink in the original revision.

*Hopefully* the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground) will help address this; as questions such as this will be reviewed before getting posted (and being able to be answered) stopping such poor quality content ever getting to the "main site". *If* the Staging ground is a successful project is another question entirely; it heavily relies on reviewers or passionate curators. Only time will tell if enough users (volunteers) will put in the effort.

Comment: Perhaps *"dont know how to add more message"* means they simply don't know what to say to describe their problem. All they know is "I wrote some code. It gives this error. What do I do now?". (I'm just trying to  guess at the OP's thought process. I'm not claiming we want questions like this on SO).